# how to recognize a modifier and a complement in an unclear NPs

Tags: syntax, complement

You can take those examples which I find very hard and show me on them which is a complement and which a modifier?

- The idea that he proposed //The idea that it will rain
  I don't know, seems similar (maybe both modifiers?).
- The man to contact for the job.// Her insistence to
  see the manuscript.
  I have no idea here (I would say both are complements).
- A belief in Politics. //A ring of gold.
  Here are again both examples complements (I would say).
- A ban on military training. // The book on the table.
  Again both modifiers (but I am just guessing).

I understand that complements are obligatory because they are licensed by the noun but I don´t know what does it mean and how can I make a test to be able to recognize them. I tried so many times but I don't see any logic in it so I often confuse their use (using a modifier instead of a complement) .

Comment: Your question is very unclear and should go in ELL anyway, and not here. I think you need to review your understanding of modifier and complement. What do you mean by switch between them?? There is nothing unclear in any of your sentences or phrases.

Comment: Relative infinitives (_the man to see, the right man to do it_) are syntactically complex and have any number of peculiarities (like only allowing relative pronouns that have been pied-piped, for instance (_the man with whom to speak_, but *_the man who(m) to speak to_).

Comment: @Lambie, In our university, we distinguish between complements as an obligatory elements and modifiers as an optional elements. I have a hard time recognizing which should be used and when.

Comment: 1A is ambiguous; could be either. 1B is a complement. 2A modifier. 2B ungrammatical. 3A Complement (cf *a belief of politics). 4A Complement. 4B modifier.

Comment: @Araucaria-him, thank you, however, you can see that I match incorrectly almost every example, can you tell me your strategy for the recognition?

Comment: @Lambie Of course there is. And one need look no further than the very first example! There, the constituent *that he proposed* could be either a relative clause modifier or, alternatively, a content clause complement of the picture noun *idea*.

Comment: @Araucaria-him I was trying to get the OP to spell it out rather than having us have to analyze it. The question itself is **not clear**.

Comment: @Lambie You wrote: "There is nothing unclear in any of your sentences or phrases."  You meant in terms of the OP's question. But there is. In fact, there are many, many things.

Comment: @Araucaria-him No, there is nothing unclear **as written**. Now, discussing their grammar is an entirely different matter.